# C# - How to get the deserialized object original string parted

Tags: c#, json

Alright, I have no idea how to even phrase my question quickly, but I can provide the following example:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(apiUrl + string.Format("/orders?status={0}&access_token={1}", orderStatusToImport, authorizationDetails.AccessToken));
    request.Method = "GET";

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

var orders = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<models.Order[]>(responseString);

var processableOrders = orders.Where(o => o.Status.ToLower() == orderStatusToImport.ToLower());

foreach (var order in processableOrders)
{
    ImportOrder(order, param1, param2, out result);
}
```

This works perfectly. However, I'd also like to save the 'original' Json. This would be 'responseString' in this case, but I **only** want the part of Json with this orders' data. Nothing more.

For example; let's say the Json has three order objects:

```
{"Orders": [
 {
  "Name":"John",
  "LastName":"Doe",
  "ItemId":5
 },
 {
  "Name":"Jane",
  "LastName":"Doe",
  "ItemId":3
 },
 {
  "Name":"Aaron",
  "LastName":"Mark",
  "ItemId":5
 }
]}
```

I'd like to save the Json for each order, seperately. So eventually I'd have a string with only:

```
{
  "Name":"Aaron",
  "LastName":"Mark",
  "ItemId":5
 }
```

How can I achieve this? I am using the Newtonsoft.Json NuGet package.

Comment: serialize each order item, separately?

Comment: Alternative is to deserialize to `JObject`. Then manually loop over order elements and call `ToObject<Order>` to obtain corresponding order. Then you can save original JSON corresponding to each order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you deserialize it, and pick that object, then serialize it to JSON, then you got what you want.

Comment: The only thing I'm afraid of is that, if there is more info than my C# object, these will be lost as it will only serialize the C# object back. But assuming this will never occur, this answer applies. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can serialize `order` object again in loop. It will give you json string of that particular order.

```
foreach (var order in processableOrders)
{
    var order_Serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(order);
    ImportOrder(order, param1, param2, out result);
}
```